# Bangla language not work in my Shiny App

Tags: r, character-encoding, shiny, shiny-server

In my shiny app I use Bangla Language but it not works. I follow there documentation, save with encoding UTF-8 but its ended with ui.R is not encoded in UTF-8.

This is my minimum skeleton:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("তথ্যসংগ্রহ"),
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)
```

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Comment: Cross-posted at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/4efvdxExXE4/wdu9ECijCwAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it your having trouble viewing the characters correctly? You could try a couple of things.

You could try forcing the page encoding in shiny to `utf-8` by setting the meta charset attribute like:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("
      $('html > head').append('<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/>');
      # To see where tag ends up 
      $('html > head').append('<meta test=\"Yupp\"/>');
      "))
  ),
  # Application title
  titlePanel("তথ্যসংগ্রহ"),
  sidebarPanel(
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

Or you could set the R encoding like:

```
options(encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Or finally you could try to call Sys.setlocale

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE","bd_BD")
```

Unfortunately I can't test this since I can't reproduce the error.